# Priority queue with insert/delmin operations in constant (amortized) running times

Tags: data-structures, queue, priority-queue

Is it possible implement a priority queue with O(1) (amortized) running time of operations `insert` and `delete_min` (delete element with the lowest priority) if I know the range of priorities?

I thought of some modification of Fibonacci heap, but it does not seem to work due to the O(logn) amortized running time of `delete_min`.

Would approach similar to bucket-sort do the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a hash table that maps each priority to it's current frequency.

When you `insert` a priority, you can do it in constant time on average: You find the entry and increment priority's frequency.

When you `delete_min` you have to traverse the hash table to find the minimum priority with non zero frequency and then decrement this frequency. But since you have a constant number of distinct priority values, this runs in constant time also. It is of theoretical value though, if the number of priorities is large.

Comment: `But since you have a known constant number of priorities, this runs in constant time also`. Can you explain ? If there are N priorities, deleting each would require traversing through the map which is N. And doing it N times makes the complexity O(N^2).

Comment: The problem claims that the range of priorities is known. For example you could have only `1, 2, 3` as possible priority values, but need to `insert` or `delete_min` to the queue `N` of them (even with repetition). Then the complexity is `O(3N)=O(N)`.

Comment: you are considering the number of priorities as N when inside queue and going over them as a constant 3(as it is a known value). But that does not change that it is a count of input which is N. So instead of `O(3N)` is should be `O(NN)`.

Comment: The input `N` of the problem is how many priority values you `insert`/`delete_min` and `3` is the number of possible priority values. Let's say we have inserted to the priority queue the values `1`, `2`, `3`, `1`, `2`, `3`. So I map each distinct priority value to it's frequency (1 => 2, 2 => 2, 3 => 2). When I want to `delete_min` I have to check only `3` entries in this mapping and not `N`.